# UILabel won't display specific String variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I have an array containing string type values, and one value of a string contains the symbol `&` and another the symbol `^`. So when it's time for them to be shown the `UILabel` remains blank.

```
let myString = arrayStrings[0] // The value is "M&M" or "(0C)^3" 
myLabel.text = myString //UILabel remains blank
```

On the other hand, when I hardcode the string, the `UILabel` displays it.

```
myLabel.text = "M&M" //UILabel displays it normally
```

What can I do?

Just realised that when I print the Array I have the following result:

```
print("Array: \(arrayStrings)" // Array: ["\0M&M\0", "\0(0C)^3\0"]
```

"\0" doesn't exist to the rest Strings of the array

Thank you!

Comment: How do you create the `arrayStrings` array? Is it filled by reading a file? Or calling a web service?

Comment: reading a csv file...meanwhile when I print(myString) it is shown normally

Comment: Try a `print("Array: \(arrayStrings)")` after it has been filled from the CSV (add that output to your question)

Comment: Thank you! Just did and realised this thing I am writing above. Why \0 was added only to these Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\0` means string termination in programming. So your String `"\0M&M\0"` means that this string is terminated on index 0, and then again later. So when you assign this string to your label, your label is displaying empty string.

To tweak it, do this and you will see the difference. Your problem is not related to & or ^

```
myLabel.text = "M&M\0 Hey I have lots of stuff here but the string is already terminated"
```

So in this situation, you need to find out why `\0` exists in your string. You can possibly remove them by regex or string replace.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I am using the String = "#$%^&" as a String separator from csv to Array. For now I will use replacingOccurences and change the separator later.